Azure airflow - Could not read served logs
When my dags run in azure airflow (UI) they are getting the error: *** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.  The error occurs when any task starts running, I don't have any other logs, and it can occur with any task.
I tried changing the configuration parameter AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__LOG_FETCH_TIMEOUT_SEC = 360 and AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__LOG_FETCH_DELAY_SEC = 2, but nothing changed.
I also tried changing the log base location but the heartbeats stop running the dags so I rolled back this update.
These updates were made to the user interface through Datafactory > Airflow.

Can you check network rules and firewalls whether they block the communications?
